# Relational Database Design Good Practice: Normalization?

Tags: database-design, jsonb

I'm working on an application and its main purpose is to recommend other users based on their preferences and based on their personality (each recommendation is treated separately).
What is consider to be a good practice? To store information in 3 separated tables (`users`, `user_preferences` and `user_details`) or to use a single table `users` with two `jsonb` columns?

Comment: Good practice depends on the type of database you're using.  If you're using a relational database, you [normalize the database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  If you're using a NoSQL database, you create documents.

Answer (score 1):

1] Considering your transaction as OLTP(Online Transaction Processing), you should plan for 3 separate tables. It will get you better performance while using various joins to retrieve table data.Always normalize your schema.

Answer (score 1):

First, one thing to note is that depending on what you are trying to do, jsonb may break first normal form.  Let's discuss 1NF and why it is a good idea:

First Normal Form exists if, and only if:

1. All rows consist of data with the same number of columns
2. All rows are unique
3. All values in all columns are atomic

Now, the first two are easily understood but the third is actually controversial.  Does it mean that everything must be maximally decomposed?  Well as long as datetime columns are allowed, it cannot mean that....

The best way to think about the atomicity requirement in my view is that every value in the table represents a single value in a domain.  Therefore two things break the atomicity requirement 1NF here.  The first are sets (using arrays where ordering doesn't matter, for example tags on blog posts), and the second is storing data in which you have internal functional dependencies.

Why do both of these matter?  Mamanging sets in columns creates a lot of opportunity for a lot of extra work in the database.  And transitive dependencies also provide problems,  You cannot have a foreign key from a field in your jsonb referencing something in another table for example.

In terms of performance, you will probably not see much difference if all you are doing is storing preferences and application blobs, so the additional functionality is important.  Note that PostgreSQL (can't speak for other dbs) will TOAST large fields.  TOASTed fields impose additional overhead in some cases but not others and it is far harder to measure the impact of this on a query than it is a join.  So that is another mark against it.  TOAST is a great technique btw but it is not a free lunch.  So you may have the same performance implications but in a far less transparent way.